# iOS block object without copying?

Tags: objective-c, ios, block

Recently I learn that if I need to keep a block object, I should copy the block, because it's created on the stack.

Then I review some of my code. I found that I was doing something like:

```
@implementation MyView
...
-(void) addButton:(NSString *)title clickAction:(void ^(void)) action {
    [self.buttons addObject:@[ title, action ] ];
}
-(void) createButtons { ... }
...
@end

...

// Somewhere in my project:
-(void) init {
     MyView *view = [MyView new];
     [view addButton:@"OK"     clickAction:^{ NSLog(@"OK");     }];
     [view addButton:@"Cancel" clickAction:^{ NSLog(@"Cancel"); }];
}
```

Basically, I add some buttons info to MyView. At some point, MyView will create the buttons. When the button is click, MyView will find out the corresponding clickAction, and invoke it.

The weird part is that this program works fine, no exception, no error.

So, why the program runs without copying the block object?

Other info :
 * iphone app ( 4.3 - 6.0 )
 * non-ARC
 * XCode 4.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Behind the scene, block implementation consists of two parts:

- The executable code of the block, and
- A data structure containing the values of the variables used in the block

Only the second part of the block is placed on the stack and copied to the heap memory; the first part is compiled to the code segment of your program, and does not get copied.

Since your block implementations do not reference any variable from the surrounding scope, the data portion of their blocks is empty. That is why your code works: there is simply nothing to copy! However, you should add block copy anyway, because otherwise a small change to the code of your block will break your application without the compiler noticing anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code will still work no matter how complex the block, since `action` is placed in a `NSArray` which will cause it to be retained by the collection...

Comment: @JodyHagins Retaining is not the problem, it's the body allocated on the stack going out of scope that will cause issues. When the method exists, the block created inside it will end up in the invalid area of memory. That is why you need to copy it onto the heap.

Comment: Right - but it is copied to the heap when the NSArray retains it.  From then on, the object in the NSArray will be the heap version, not the original stack block.  If you call retain on a stack-based-block, it will copy it to the heap, then retain it.

Comment: @JodyHagins I am reasonably certain that simply sending `retain` to a stack object is not enough to make a stack copy of it.

Comment: Blocks get treated special.  It's been so long since I've used non-ARC blocks, I was thinking that it would `Block_copy` as part of retain, since it knows it is on the stack (and blocks get treated special in other circumstances)... but that would break the definition that says retain must return the same instance...  I even ran a small test before posting my last comment to prove to myself... and didn't uncheck the ARC box...  I'll remove my post, and leave this comment as confirmation that I'm an idiot...  and promise to never answer another non-ARC-specific question :-)

Comment: You're right. It throws error immediately when I reference self in that block.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler creates different types of blocks depending on what the block does. If a block doesn't capture any variables then it can be represented by an `NSGlobalBlock` (`NSGlobalBlock` is little more than a function pointer). I suspect that's what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like you and @dasblinkenlight shares same opinion. I'm going to accept dasblinkenlight's answer, because his answer is more detailed.